# Configuring SMS gateway?

Tags: sms-gateway

I want to configure sms gateway. my scenario is as:

We have a list of enrolled students. Each one is assigned a tutor. They have to get information about their tutor such as tutor name and contact etc.

I want that they send a formatted sms to the server and server provides the requested information to them via sms.

Please tell me what things, I will need?
Infrastructure? 
any demo server available to test my application?

I will be implementing it in PHP

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen Twilio's REST API for SMS already? https://www.twilio.com/sms/api. That will save you lots of time configuring own GSM modem firmware and maintaining own SMS transactions. With 3rd party SMS service provider you can just focus on your client app such as sending back tutor's profile to the provider and the provider will carry your message push it back to the student's mobile number.

Of course the old way is that everything (data and GSM software) sits within our own network. I used to have HTC's GSM model like 7 years ago) with my J2ME apps for Nokia, HTC and Motorola smartphones. But nowadays, you have lots or cheaper and better options. Even Android phones can be used as bare bones GSM modem already :D

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Before you go on implementing something by yourself, I suggest that you check services that already do it well. Maybe you can just use them? One such easy-to-use service is [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/sms).